# Getting VS2013/SSRS to permanently use a .SQL file instead of manually pasting/importing queries for a dataset

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, dataset, file-access

First time posting here, want to start by saying thanks to the community here for the amazing insights I've enjoyed over the years

I build reports with SSRS in VS2013 and currently have to paste/import MySQL statements every time I create/update the datasets.  I want VS2013/SSRS to permanently refer to a local .SQL file instead of having me manually paste the query text every time I need to update it. How does I do this?

In my ideal world, I would have a folder bank full of SQL query files that VS would use to acquire data from the DB for the reports. Then all I would have to do is alter the separate, local SQL files and VS would take it from there.

I see 3 vectors for supplying the SQL query to the dataset: 1) Paste/Import the text query, 2) Table access, 3)Stored procedures.  I thought there might be a way thru Stored Procedures but I'm not having any luck discovering if it's possible and how to code it from documentation and the web.

If it's useful, Visual Studio 2013 is platformed on a Windows server O/S.

Answer (score 0):

Create your script as a stored procedure on the server you're querying. Configure all your reports based on that dataset to run that stored procedure. When you update the stored procedure, all reports that use that SP are affected by the code change.